# How to load a formatted txt file into Python to be searched

Tags: python, file, search

I have a file that is formatted with different indentation and which is several hundred lines long and I have tried various methods to load it into python as a file and variable but have not been successful. What would be an efficient way to load the file. My end goal is to load the file, and and search it for a specific line of text.

```
with open('''C:\Users\Samuel\Desktop\raw.txt''') as f:
    for line in f:
        if line == 'media_url':
    print line
        else:
           print "void"

Error: Traceback (most recent call last): File "<pyshell#35>", line 1, in <module> with open('''C:\Users\Samuel\Desktop\raw''') as f: IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('r') or filename: 'C:\\Users\\Samuel\\Desktop\raw
```

Comment: Post your script and people will be able to tell you if it can be optimised.

Comment: This is what I am doing so far from @Istvan Chung. And I am still getting an error that reads:  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#35>", line 1, in <module>
    with open('''C:\Users\Samuel\Desktop\raw''') as f:
IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('r') or filename: 'C:\\Users\\Samuel\\Desktop\raw'

Comment: Add the error message and other relevant info to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Python uses backslash to mean "escape".  For Windows paths, this means giving the path as a "raw string" -- 'r' prefix.
2. lines have newlines attached. To compare, strip them.

   with open(r'C:\Users\Samuel\Desktop\raw.txt') as f:
       for line in f:
           if line.rstrip() == 'media_url':
              print line
           else:
              print "void"

Comment: I still get an error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#5>", line 1, in <module>
    with open("r'C:\Users\Samuel\Desktop\raw.txt'", "r") as f:
IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('r') or filename: "r'C:\\Users\\Samuel\\Desktop\raw.txt'"

Comment: the path should have double backslashes, or the "r" prefix, but not both.  It's confusing :)  I suggest putting the data file in the same directory with the Python file and debugging from there.

Answer (score 2):

The following is the standard way of reading a file's contents into a variable:

```
with open("filename.txt", "r") as f:
    contents = f.read()
```

Use the following if you want a list of lines instead of the whole file in a string:

```
with open("filename.txt", "r") as f:
    contents = list(f.read())
```

You can then search for text with

```
if any("search string" in line for line in contents):
    print 'line found'
```

Comment: Please don't use `readlines`. Just call `list(contents)` if you *really* want to, although for single passes the file alone should be fine.

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to search for a specific line, then it's much better to avoid loading the whole file in:

```
with open('filename.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        if line == 'search string':  # or perhaps: if 'search string' in line:
            # do something
```

If you're trying to search for the presence of a specific line while ignoring indentation, you'll want to use

```
        if line.strip() == 'search string'.strip():
```

in order to strip off the leading (and trailing) whitespace before comparing.

Comment: If the file is stored on my desktop as raw.txt, how should I identify it in place of 'filename.txt'

Comment: @user3672652 *nix, Mac: `'~/Desktop/raw.txt'`; Windows (IIRC): `'''C:\Documents and Settings\<username>\Desktop\raw.txt'''`

Comment: This is the error I get when I run the code and what I encountered before: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#24>", line 1, in <module>
    with open('C:\Users\Samuel\Desktop\raw.txt') as f:
IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('r') or filename: 'C:\\Users\\Samuel\\Desktop\raw.txt'

Comment: @user3672652 The triple quotes are significant.

Comment: I added the quotes but continue to get the same error.

Comment: @user3672652 I apologize; it should be a raw literal rather than a triple-quote literal: `r'C:\Users\Samuel\Desktop\raw.txt'`